# Using 0 < x < 10 as a condition in an equation

Tags: conditional

How do I write 0 < x < 10 on the right side in the equation. If #1 + #2 is bigger than 0 and smaller than 10. And is it possible to require -10 < x < 10 with the additional condition x != 0

```
If[#1 + #2 == ??, ... ]
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want here. If you're testing the summed slots then you can just say `0<#1+#2<10` and it'll return `True`/`False` if the sum is in/out of that range.

Comment: The syntax for `Less[ ]` is `Less[1, 2, 3, ...]` or the shorthand `1 < 2 < 3` Try them out

Comment: I am using this `If[Last[#3 - #2] == 0 && First[#2 - #1] == 1,
    "01 X" <> ToString@First@#2 <> " Y" <> ToString@Last@#2,
  Unevaluated@
    Sequence[
      "00 X" <> ToString@First@#2 <> " Y" <> ToString@Last@#2, 
      "01 X" <> ToString@First@#2 <> " Y" <> ToString@Last@#2]
  ] &` and would like to get 0 < X <10 instead of 0 but i can't seem to make it work. EDIT: just saw your last comment, going to try it.

Comment: I have tried the following and something similar: Example: `list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}` `Last[#1 + #2] == [Less[5] && Greater[3]] &` , not sure if I should use == at all, i dont know what to do.

Comment: try to add a clear explanation of what you are actually trying to accomplish (edit the question, not in comment)

Comment: As @belisariushassettled points out, what you probably want is `Less[3, Last[#1+#2],5]&`, meaning 3 < (sum) < 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put more conditions in with the "and" operator "&&", e.g.:

```
Plot[If[x < 1 && x > 0, 2, -2], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

And you second example would be

```
If[{-10 < x < 10 && x != 0}, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [ConditionalExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) or [Condition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) or [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
f[x_] := x^2 /; 0 < x < 10
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

```
h[x_] := 3 x/Sin[x] /; -10 < x < 10 && x != 0
Plot[h[x], {x, -20, 20}]
```

[image]

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{-x^2, 0 < x < 10}, {2 x, -10 < x < 10 && x != 0}}]
Plot[g[x], {x, -20, 20}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

And with [Assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)

```
FunctionExpand[x^2/Sin[x], Assumptions -> 0 < x < 10]
```

> x^2 Csc[x]

```
Plot[x^2 Csc[x], {x, -37.6991, 37.6991}]
```

[image]